# How do I fix an InputMismatchException error that comes from scanner incorrectly reading a file?

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to simply read the first thing in a file and set a variable to hold that value. The first line of the file is `10` (see below) and I am using `.nextInt()` to try to read the value but I am getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at project5.Project5.readPlayers(Project5.java:39)
at project5.Project5.main(Project5.java:19)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
private static Player[] readPlayers( String fileName ) {
    String name = "", catchPhrase = "";
    int age = 0, count = 0;

    //set up to read the file
    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(fileName);

    //read the first line
    int numPlayers = inStream.nextInt();
    inStream.nextLine();

    //create arrays, one to hold all the possible players and one to hold if they are old enough
    Player[] allPlayers = new Player[numPlayers];
    boolean[] oldEnough = new boolean[numPlayers];
```

Here is the file:

```
10
Rincewind 28 Luggage! 
MoistVonLipwig 30 Postal!
CaptainCarrotIronfoundersson 20 I am a 6'6 dwarf
GrannyWeatherwax 88 I ate'nt dead!
Eskarina 22 8th! 
Tiffany 19 Cheese! 
Vetinari 52 Si non confectus, non reficiat 
Igor 180 What goeth around, cometh around... or thtopth 
NobbyNobbs 17 tis a lie sir, i never done it 
DaftWullie 45 Aye, Criverns!
```

All I am trying to do is read the `10` and move to the next line with my code.

Comment: The file is in the project folder and it is spelled correctly and everything. It just isn't reading the 10 as an int.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, this was my first question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're passing in a string (that contains the filename) to `Scanner` which it interprets literally. So if `fileName = "test.txt"`, all your scanner contains is `"test.txt"` (and not the contents of the file). So when you do `scanner.nextInt()`, it throws an exception as there is no next ints to be found (you'd only be able to `scanner.next()` to get the `fileName` back). However, what you want to do is pass in a file handler (using `File`) into `Scanner`, which'll then read the contents of the file into the stream which you can then manipulate like you're trying to.

What you want to do is:

```
try {
    File file = new File(fileName);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner inStream = new Scanner(file);
```

This'll read in the file contents into the `Scanner` allowing you do do what you're expecting. (Note: `File` comes from `java.io.File`)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize I was just passing a string along. You sir are a life saver.